# Show that $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(th) - f(0)}{t}$ exists if $f$ is differentiable in $0 \in \mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: real-analysis

> Show from the definition of differentiability that if $f: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable in $0 \in \mathbb{R}^m$, for each $h \in \mathbb{R}^m$: $$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(th) - f(0)}{t}$$ exists.

So because $f$ is differentiable in $0$:
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0) - L(x)}{||x||} = 0
$$

I know we can write:
$$
Df(0)[h] = L(h) = L(x-0)
$$

From there I am lost. Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$f(th)-f(0) =  Df(0)(th) + o(|th|) = tDf(0)(h) + o(|th|),$$

where the linearity of $Df(0)$ was used. Divide the right side by $t$ to get $Df(0)(h) + o(|th|)/t.$ Now argue that $o(|th|)/t\to 0.$